# Update a tensor using Scatter_Update

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a weights Tensor of shape `(300,)`, which has binary data, some elements are `1's` and others are `0's`. I need to convert all the `1's` except the first occurrence of `1` to `0's`. I would love to know of a simple method to do so in Tensorflow.

But, this is how I'm currently trying to achieve this:

I get all the indices of where the tensor is 1 with this line of code:

```
indices = tf.squeeze(tf.where(tf.greater(weights, 0)))
```

Then, I build a tensor that will updated on corresponding indices:

```
updates = tf.constant(0., shape=indices[1:].eval(session=sess2).shape, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Then, I use `scatter_update` to update *updates* on corresponding *indices*, but since `scatter_update` only works on a Variable, I create a variable and assign the updatable tensor to this variable, like so:

```
 weights_var = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(weights.get_shape()), name="weights_var")
tf.assign(weights_var, weights)
```

Then, I call `tf.scatter_update`:

```
tf.scatter_update(weights_subset, indices[1:], updates).eval(session=sess2)
```

It's giving me following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-211-c863dff9ffc7> in <module>()
     51 updates = tf.constant(0., shape=indices[1:].eval(session=sess2).shape, dtype=tf.float32)
     52 
---> 53 tf.scatter_update(weights_subset, indices[1:], updates).eval(session=sess2)
     54 
     55 # print(final_weights.eval(session=sess2))

~/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py in scatter_update(ref, indices, updates, use_locking, name)
    290     to use the updated values after the update is done.
    291   """
--> 292   if ref.dtype._is_ref_dtype:
    293     return gen_state_ops.scatter_update(ref, indices, updates,
    294                                         use_locking=use_locking, name=name)

AttributeError: 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute '_is_ref_dtype'
```

I'd love to know solution to this and if possible an easier, vectorised one-liner in Tensorflow. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your problem then this code flow should work according to the first paragraph in your question. Don't know if it can be further shortened.

```
mask = tf.Variable([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])

indices = tf.squeeze(tf.where(tf.greater(mask, 0)))
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

valuesofindices = np.delete(indices.eval(session=sess),
                            0)

update = tf.scatter_update(mask,
                           valuesofindices,
                           tf.tile(tf.constant([0],
                                   tf.int32),
                           valuesofindices.shape))

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(update.eval(session=sess))
```

Output :

> [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]